# rails rspec testing updating attribute on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a very simple model called `Reminder` with a boolean attribute of `verified` and I want to test my method `update_verified` which simply sets the attribute `verified` to `true`. I'm using rspec and factory girl.

```
# reminder.rb
  def update_verified
    self.update(verified: true)
  end 

# reminder_spec.rb
  describe "#update_verified" do
    it "should mark the reminder.verified to true" do
      reminder = build(:reminder, verified: false)
      reminder.update_verified

      expect(reminder.verified).to eq(true)
    end
  end
```

For some reason, when I run the test, the new value of `true` for the attribute `verified` is not being persisted. However, when I run the method in console, it works fine. Thoughts?

```
  1) Reminder#update_verified should mark the reminder.verified to true
     Failure/Error: expect(reminder.verified).to eq(true)

       expected: true
            got: false

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/reminder_spec.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.19193 seconds (files took 7.07 seconds to load)
```

Comment: hilarious, I had the EXACT same problem nearly 6 months later.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to reload your object:

```
expect(reminder.reload.verified).to eq(true)
```

Comment: that didn't quite do it. It still returned `false`. But if I run `reminder.update_verified` twice within the spec, then it passes.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me

```
expect do
  reminder.update_verified
  reminder.reload
end.to change(reminder, :verified).from(false).to(true)
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this helpful to check if the method saves changes to an object in the database:

```rb
expect { reminder.update_verified }.to change(reminder, :updated_at)
```

**Explanation**

Calling `self.update(verified: true)` does not only update the `verified`-column, but also the `updated_at`-column. We can then check for changes in the `updated_at`-column to verify that changes to the object has been saved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `reload` on object.
And please follow rspec [best practices](http://betterspecs.org/): use `let` and `subject`.

```
describe "#update_verified" do
  let(:reminder) { build(:reminder, verified: false) }
  subject { reminder.update_verified }
  it "should mark the reminder.verified to true" do
    subject
    expect(reminder.reload.verified).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**
The problem is in `build` method. It creates new object and does not save object to DB.
Replace `build` with `create` method.

Comment: Thanks for your additional tips. However, the `.reload` isn't seeming to do the trick. Still getting false unless I run `reminder.update_verified` twice... which seems weird!

Comment: try to use `create` instead of `build`

Comment: Just to give more perspective on the "best practise" thing, extracting `let`s and using `subject` (at all) is something I know several experienced teams actively avoid. Arguably the code as written in the question is more straightforward. So by all means consider the suggested style, but it's not a recognised "best practise" in my experience.

Comment: If you got more than 1 spec in `describe` `subject` allows you not to duplicate method name. And `let` allow you to create `context`s with ease. There are other more important reasons but these are just the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

That's quite strange, but I think you should change from the `build(:reminder, verified: false)` to `create(:reminder, verified: false)` then use the `reload` method as others have specified above.

Answer (score 2):

`update_column`  can always work no matter  you use `let` or `build`

Comment: You SAVED my day! I was fighting with this for hours. In my case I was trying to update a `let` variable like this: `user.update(created_at: Date.yesterday.to_s)`, and it did update it in the variable but not in the database (`User.first.created_at` was still returning `Date.today`). Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your object is not persisted yet, when you first time call `reminder.update_verified`. Instead of update, it will just create an object with assigned attributes. When you call it for a second time, it will work properly, because object is persisted. You need to change build to create and it's gonna work.